# Kill program in a bat file

Tags: command-line, batch, kill

In a command file, startup.cmd, I have something like

```
start "program.exe"
```

I would like to do the following:

```
if running, stop program.exe
start program.exe
```

I tried

taskkill program.exe

If the process is not running though, I get an error - and I don't want to get errors...
Not sure if this is not too violent a kill, either.

How can I stop my program if it is running, before starting it ? (if it starts while another instance of itself is running, results may be unpredictable...)

(Windows)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the following:

```
Taskkill /IM program.exe /FI "STATUS eq RUNNING" /F
```

Comment: Thank you, I was just finding it - I still get an error when the process is not running... is there anything to find out if the process is running ?

Comment: I got it - use the /FI option !!!

Answer (score 0):

Just keep in mind that bat file should be in `C:/` not other drives If so it will not work and give you an `Access Denied` error. So be careful.

Comment: I did check for the local drive but thank you for adding this